# FB.login() doesn't work on Firefox javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am building website with login facebook and twitter 
fb.login not working on firefox
its working fine on chrome
can anybody help me to solve my issue

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console? can you show your code or we can guess

Comment: ReferenceError: FB is not defined
 

function _login() {
    FB.login(function (response) {        
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
             statusChangeCallback(response);
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}
its showing error  but working fine on chrome and @JaromandaX

Comment: ReferenceError: FB is not defined

Comment: I meant in the question. Code is impossible to read in a comment